# how to ignore some xml node when translating Json to xml?

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson

My Json input is like:

```
{"PickerInput":{"Pick":[{"@name":"L0C4R0"},{"@name":"L0C0R0"},{"@name":"L0C3R0"}]}}
```

My actural XML is like:

```
<PickerInput>**<Pick>**<Pick name="L0C4R0"></Pick><Pick name="L0C0R0"></Pick><Pick name="L0C3R0"></Pick>**</Pick>**</PickerInput>
```

My EXPECT XML is like:

```
<PickerInput><Pick name="L0C4R0"></Pick><Pick name="L0C0R0"></Pick><Pick name="L0C3R0"></Pick></PickerInput>
```

**Question:**how to remove the wraped Pick node in XML?thanks in advance.

My class defined:

```
public class PickerInput {
        public NameBean[] Pick;
    }
    public static class NameBean {
        @JsonProperty("@name")
        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="name",isAttribute = true)
        public String name;
    }
```